# How to install php 5.3 on windows 10 / 64bit / wampserver 64bit?

Tags: php, windows-10, 64-bit

I am to work on a project currently running on php 5.3.
The only php exe [I found for windows](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/) is : php-5.3.29-Win32-VC9-x86.zip. 
No x64 version found. 
So far, my firt try at installing locally ([wampserver 64bits](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download-wampserver-64bits/)) has failed : Apache will not start with php5_module pointing to the "php-5.3.29-Win32-VC9-x86.zip" executable (dll).

**Can anyone confirm php 5.3 can actually run on a 64bits pc** ?

If confirmed as feasable, can you please help me ? (which download to use, should I use IIS/fastCGI instead, etc. ?)

Thanks in advance for any help,

Paco

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not really the answer you want, but you REALLY should not use 5.3 .. It hasn't gotten any security patches in 3 years. If you project is not compatible with 7.1, you should at least be using 5.6.

You can get that here: http://windows.php.net/download#php-5.6

Answer (score 0):

Try XAMPP. It runs on both x64 and x32 bit Windows PC
https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: So does [Wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/) ;-) : the question is "can php 5.3 run on a 64bit windows ?"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is of course yes.

PHP on IIS goes through FastCGI, so that even on 64 bit Windows the IIS components are 64 bit, `php-cgi.exe` as FastCGI client can run as 32 bit. You should try to run 32 bit of PHP 5.x as based on observation the corresponding 64 bit builds (if available) are not as stable as it should.

Like others commented, you really should upgrade now to 7.x (even 5.6 reaches end of life in 2018), or never.